# Как посчитать количество символов определенного типа в строке?

Tags: javascript

Например:
w5*5-G+H - 1 маленькая буква, 2 цифры, 2 заглавные буквы, 3 символа.

Comment: через регулярные выражения вытягивать определенные символы или буквы и отдельно посчитывать

Comment: длина массива в match с модификатором g например:

     'ttttarrr'.match(/(?=([a-z]))\1{2,2}/g).length ["tt", "tt", "rr"] //3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

А почему не воспользоваться регулярками и методом .match(), как писали в комментариях выше?

Так и быстрее будет, и кода в разы меньше:

```
var text = 'w5*5-G+H'
  , upper = text.match(/[A-Z]/g).length
  , lower = text.match(/[a-z]/g).length
  , nums = text.match(/[0-9]/g).length
  ;
```

Только я не смог вспомнить нормальной регулярки для символов, но это можно сделать самому

Comment: зачем вырезать. В соотвествии с примером выше все остальное это символы: text.length - upper + lower + number; Мне так кажется.

Comment: @MrFranke, вот из-за таких приемов программирования почти все современные программы жрут много памяти, еле шевелятся и полны багов.

Comment: @avp И чем этот пример так плох?
Мой вариант работает быстрее, вот пруф:
http://jsperf.com/match-test-09

Так что учите матчасть, перед тем как давать советы

Comment: @avp, мне кажется вы и @lampa не правы. во первых, этот код работает быстрее...

http://jsperf.com/match-loop7834

во вторых, я практически уверен что цикл на js всегда  будет работать медленнее чем простой регексп на C :) и памяти сожрет меньше, ну а насчет багов... в `if(){} else if(){} else if(){}` куда проще ошибиться. что собственно и сделано. character неопределен, переменные не объявлены.

Comment: @lampa а зачем ? давайте тогда и в ваш скрипт в ту строчку где символы добавим все utf8 символы.

Comment: @eicto убрать проверку символов в конец и заменить конструкцию 

    "<>@!#$%^&*()_+[]{}?:;|'\"\\,./~`-=".indexOf(char)

на 

    else

Потом 

    !isNaN(char * 1)

заменить на что-нибудь менее ресурсоемкое и скрипт будет быстрее.

И вот быстрый пример:

 for(var i=0, upper=0, lower=0, digits=0, symbols=0, char, all_letters = str.length; i < all_letters; i++) {
  char = str.charAt(i);

  
  if (char == char.toUpperCase()) {
   upper++;
  }
  else if (char == char.toLowerCase()) {
   lower++;
  }
  else if (char >=0 || char < 0) {
   digits++;
  }
  else {
   symbols++;
  }
 }

Comment: Не забудьте с таким способом поставить проверки на null у регулярок. Сейчас обновленный код в 3 раза быстрее.

Comment: Мне кажется проблема даже не в isNaN, а в том, что регулярки каждый раз заново проходятся по всей строке. Я на скорую руку оптимизировал мой вариант, но он все равно медленнее на 20%:

    var str = 'w5*5-G+H'
      , upperStr = str.replace(/[A-Z]/g, '')
      , upper = str.length - upperStr.length

      , lowerStr = upperStr.replace(/[a-z]/g, '')
      , lower = upperStr.length - lowerStr.length

      , numsStr = lowerStr.replace(/[0-9]/g, '')
      , nums = lowerStr.length - numsStr.length;

Comment: @eicto не знаю как вы тестируете, у меня тоже мой пример выигрывает. Про регулярные - если выражения захешить (ну тупо в переменные завести), то еще добавится чуть к скорости.

Comment: @eicto Странно, но теперь и у меня loop медленнее match. Чудеса)
http://jsperf.com/match-loop7834/3 - новый вариант работает на 60% быстрее

Comment: > я чего-то не понимаю или у меня хром такой особенный ? у меня в хроме loop медленнее match

@lampa я не  вижу в списке вашего браузера, это не IE7 ? так там вообще js работает в разы хуже ем chrome/firefox вот [здесь](http://jsperf.com/match-loop7834) вообще специально всю инициализацию вынес из вашей функции за тесты, и получаю match на 50% быстрее. в firefox то-же самое

Comment: @eicto я то тестирую с помощью своей ф-ции https://github.com/lampaa/JSTF , прим: http://jsfiddle.net/tV6z8/

Comment: @lampa вы немного неправильно тестировали, я заметил что он первое сообщение выдает, пока fiddle грузится поэтому я приделал к кнопке "start" запуск: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/tV6z8/2/

и примерно такие результаты:

match: 224.698ms (index):31
loop: 1510.678ms (index):31
match: 143.283ms (index):31
loop: 1887.330ms (index):31
match: 151.041ms (index):31
loop: 1822.111ms (index):31
match: 153.705ms (index):31
loop: 1834.590ms (index):31

Answer (score 5):

```
var str = 'w5*5-G+H';
var all_letters = str.length;

for(var i=0, upper=0, lower=0, digits=0, symbols=0, char; i < all_letters; i++) {
    char = str.charAt(i);

    if (!isNaN(char * 1)){
        digits++;
    }
    else if("<>@!#$%^&*()_+[]{}?:;|'\"\\,./~`-=".indexOf(char) != -1) {
        symbols++;
    }
    else if (char == char.toUpperCase()) {
        upper++;
    }
    else if (char == char.toLowerCase()){
        lower++;
    }
}
```

Обновлено:

```
for(var i=0, upper=0, lower=0, digits=0, symbols=0, char, all_letters = str.length; i < all_letters; i++) {
    char = str.charAt(i);

    if (char == char.toUpperCase()) {
        upper++;
    }
    else if (char == char.toLowerCase()) {
        lower++;
    }
    else if (!isNaN(char)) {
        digits++;
    }
    else {
        symbols++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Хотя второй пример нерабочий.